# Separated DLL against multiple IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, dll

Not sure if the title is clear but thanks for any help in advance.

I have a server-client product which the server side was code via ASP.NET(WSDL), running on IIS; Client application is actually running on tablet also connecting to the IIS service, calling DLL.

Currently, my DLL has a function to tell me who is actually login on the tablet, however, I found the problem  when more than two tablet login at the same time - it seems that IIS processor can't separate the thread or process calling DLL. Therefore, DLL(server application) is displaying the incorrect login.

My question is - is there any way to limit IIS processor or make sure it is only hooking to one thread which raised from client side? I found that web garden / web farm could be a solution but I was failed to implement it.

Thanks again for any help, sorry for bad English

Comment: Are you sure its an IIS issue and not a bug in the DLL? Who wrote the DLL - have you unit tested the methods to simulate multiple log-ins?

Comment: HI Rob, thanks for replying. I am calling the DLL which is code by another team. It was working fine on the desktop however, it seems getting trouble while calling from IIS service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with the DLL. Perhaps, the login information was put in the global static variable inside the DLL. So, the scenario that I could think of:

```
1. User login and the login information was stored in the global static variable in DLL.
2. Another user login again, and the login information was stored in the global static variable in DLL. 
3. So, whatever stored in point 1, was overwritten by point 2 as the variable was global and static.
```

Hope it helps.